# What's wrong with my MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm not getting any errors as such just a minor performance issue.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
a.nid,
a.title,
a.uid,
b.parent,
b.weight,
c.name,
d.value
FROM table1 AS a INNER JOIN table2 AS b ON a.vid = b.vid AND a.status = 1
INNER JOIN table3 AS c ON c.uid = a.uid
INNER JOIN table4 AS d ON d.content_id = a.nid AND d.value_type = 'percent' AND d.function = 'average'
```

When I look at which tables are being referenced, everything is fine, but from table4 where it should only be selecting the "value" field, I'm getting an ALL being called...

```
id  select_type     table   type      possible_keys                                   key     key_len   ref                   rows  Extra
1   SIMPLE          a     ref     PRIMARY,vid,status,uid,node_status_type,nid   status  4         const                 1    
1   SIMPLE          b     eq_ref    PRIMARY                                         PRIMARY 4         databasename.a.vid    1    
1   SIMPLE          c     eq_ref    PRIMARY                                         PRIMARY 4         databasename.a.uid    1   Using where
1   SIMPLE          d     ALL     NULL                                          NULL      NULL      NULL                  2     Using where
```

As you can see, it's selecting * from the final table (d). Why is it doing this when I only need ONE field selected from it? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Thanks so much guys! I've made all three primary and now it works! Perhaps I should read up on that indexing...
Thanks again!

Comment: What was primary before? Is there another unique index? You can get the same effectiveness with just a generic non-unique index. If nid is unique, it should still be primary to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: Why did you rollback the tags?  This question has nothing to do with PHP ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ALL` means all rows, not all columns.  Since it says there are no possible keys, I'd guess that you don't have an index on d.content_id or d.value_type or d.function.

If you wanted to be fancy, you could put an index across all 3 of those columns.

Comment: Agreed - and that would probably mean 1 multifield index on all three columns, not 3 indexes, one on each. And it wouldn't even need to be considered fancy.

Answer (score 2):

Are d.value_type and d.function indexed fields? That would be initial instinct as to the cause.

Comment: Unlikely. nid is most likely the most selective therefore most useful index on a single field. But see RoBorg response re: multifield index.

Answer (score 1):

Add a multi-column index to `table4` based on the `content_type`, `value_type` and `function` columns.

Your query isn't selecting all the columns from `table4`, it's selecting all the rows; this isn't much of a problem when there's only two.

Note that a MySQL query execution plan might not give the give the answer you expect when you're working with a small number of records; it can be faster for the database to do a  full table scan in those circumstances.